# Dashboard F5 data download

Tags: health-monitoring, f5

In F5>Statistics>Dashboard it is possible to download raw data with the 'history' icon.
I need to download this on regular basis so automation comes into place.

I can't find such report in F5 regular report depository. I tried to link F5 to zabbix to analyze there but I don't have access to F5 backend. I set up a UI macro but I would like to have something more reliable in place.

Any tips most welcomed.
[F5dashboard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/civyz.png)
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [External Monitoring](https://techdocs.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/bigip-external-monitoring-implementations-12-0-0.html) will answer on how to monitor your device instead of re-inventing the wheel. It's not clear what you tried with Zabbix, configuring SNMP on F5 should be enough to connect any monitoring system.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on version 13, you have the option to load the Telemetry streaming iControl LX RPM onto BIG-IP and pull the data from any number of preconfigured systems or set up a generic pull JSON request through the API for the same data.

https://clouddocs.f5.com/products/extensions/f5-telemetry-streaming/latest/

This is the same set of data that they use to populate the BIG-IQ Centralized Management performance and health analytics.

The caveat is depending on what you request and how much you request, it can start to tax the system so enable what you need and in chunks to see how it affects system performance.  I've seen the mightiest systems grid to a halt when asked to provide ALL telemetry data to Splunk or Sumologic.

Hope this helps.